# iOS App Engine Authentication Cookie

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, authentication, cookies, uiwebview

In my iOS app I have a WebView, that uses my GAE app to authenticate. Login is working fine, and I am able to see the cookie data.

Example cookie data I see after I authenticate: (ACSID shortened for brevity)

```
=======
2012-06-16 10:00:13.784 FooApp[6342:12203] <NSHTTPCookie version:0 name:"ACSID" value:"AJKiYcGJTQ964S0JF7Rp5H" expiresDate:2012-06-30 13:57:59 +0000 created:2012-06-16 13:58:01 +0000 (3.61548e+08) sessionOnly:FALSE domain:"foo.appspot.com" path:"/" isSecure:FALSE>
=====
```

2 questions..

1. Is checking that the ACSID has a value enough to prove authentication? If not, what should I check for?
2. Is it possible to get the email address a user logged in with?

Thanks!
B

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't rely on undocumented behavior -- if you want to know whether a user's logged in, and the user's email address, send that info back in an HTTP response to your client directly.

Nothing says the behavior ACSID cookie won't arbitrarily change.

Comment: Moishe, thx for your reply as well, I will keep this in mind. I am wondering though, is the cookie even created if the user is not authenticated?

Comment: The cookie is created when user login at yourapp.appspot.com/_ah/login/?.... After login, you have to store the cookie for every sub sequence request.

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried do this on iOS yet. But on Android I'm using App Engine Rest Client to authenticate. I see they store and restore cookie for every request. So I believe it will definitely work on iOS.

I had a very hard time trying to include ACSID cookie for every request and it actually works. You have to ensure they are really in the request header on server. If you success to authenticate with app engine. You can view the CGI environment in appstats and see authentication information.

Here is the link for android client authenticator on app engine https://code.google.com/p/aerc/. You can have a look and reimplement on iOS.

If you want user email address and can get it from user object on app engine `users.get_current_user().email()`  and request it from your client app via http request.

Hope it helps

Comment: Cuong, thanks for your reply. I will play around with what you mentioned.